# Crank no start!

Tags: chevrolet, cranks-wont-run, malibu, camshaft-position-sensor

I have a 2011 Malibu 2LT. It cranks but does not start. It happened all of a sudden with no warning or issues before. Checked fuses and they were all ok, including starter relay and fuel pump relay. There is a code p0341 on the OBD, which indicates a camshaft sensor issue. I changed that with a new one but still no start. Not sure what the problem is and what I’m missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Your description leans more towards a crank position sensor then the camshaft, but if you got a p0341, that's definitely camshaft related.

Comment: You must check further. Just because the camshaft sensor (or the crank position sensor) is good doesn't necessarily mean that all of the sensors' connectors and wiring are operating correctly.

Comment: Can you test fuel and pressure at the fuel test valve on the fuel rail? It's the same as a tire valve, covered with a black(?) plastic cap. Turn on ignition without starting, cover the fuel test valve loosely with a rag and depress the valve stem, expecting a fuel spray. GM fuel pumps may run for a few seconds then shut down if the engine isn't started, enough to pressurize the fuel rail/injectors. Remove spark plugs and examine them for raw fuel. Several failed starting attempts should flood the engine. A spark test is next. No fuel on plugs+zero spark=dead crank sensor.

Comment: All tests mentioned turned out ok. Problem still there. I changed both camshaft sensors and crankshaft sensor but still no start.